# export table/view names with column names from sql server 2005 database

Tags: sql-server-2005, data-mapping

data mapping exercise approaches (3000+ tables) and I can get table names out (thanks to previous Stack Overflow answer) but is there easy way to get all table & view names and their associated columns, ideally with foreign and primary keys noted?  Newbie here so answers need to be be very simple please!  Many thanks, Jules.

Answer (score 0):

You can query information_schema.view_column_usage to see what tables and columns are used by a view.  Then query back to the other data that you have already pulled to see the primary and foreign keys.

```
select * from information_schema.view_column_usage
```

Comment: Thanks very much, but I think I'm going to steer as far away from views as I can when migrating data to the new software! Cheers, Jules

Comment: Usually there isn't much need for views, especially if you are using an ORM.